# How do I refactor nest if-statements for this block of code?

Tags: dart

In what way can I refactor nested if statements like this? A condition is met, however there are some exceptions to the condition. I recognize that this starts to approach the [Arrow Anti-Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern).

Specifically, are there any dart language features that can help me refactor or re-write this code to be more clear?

Let's use "leap years" as an example:

```dart
// on every year that is evenly divisible by 4
//   except every year that is evenly divisible by 100
//     unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400
bool isLeapYear(int year) {
  assert(!year.isNegative);
  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
      if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining boolean checks with boolean returns.
That probably means you can do it all in one expression.

I'd do:

```dart
bool isLeapYear(int year) => 
    year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
```

(Now, if you want to *optimize*, then modulo, `%`, is more expensive than bitwise and, `&`, so you can also do:

```dart
bool isLeapYear(int year) =>
  year & 3 == 0 && (year & 15 == 0 || year % 100 != 0);
```

which should be slightly more efficient. Doing `& 15`, aka `% 16`, is sufficient to detecting being a multiple of 400 if you know the number is a multiple of 100.)

For the *general case*, you can reverse your `if` branches and return early:

```dart
bool isLeapYear(int year) {
  if (year % 4 != 0) return false; // Not multiple of 4.
  // Year is a multiple of 4.
  if (year % 100 != 0) return true; // Not multiple of 100.
  // Year is a multiple 100.
  return year % 400 == 0;
}
```

(Noticing that

```dart
 if (year % 400 == 0) {
   return true;
 }
 return false;
```

is the same as `return year % 400 == 0;`.)

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. I am not very familiar with using dart's bitwise operators. I should take some time to see what I can use :)

Comment: Leave this kind of optimization to your compiler. Write the code as it is meant to work.